# Oracle - select from customer record from master table and its history table

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables - account table, loan table and loan_history table.
loan to account is 1 to many relation.

For all the customer records in loan table I wanted the details from account table. In addition I wanted the customer records that are in loan_history but not in loan master table and get the details from account table.

How can this be achieved in single query?

Sample:

```
select loan.id, acct1.number, acct1.type
from loan, acct1
where loan.cust_id = acct1.cust_id
and acct1.id = (select max(acct2.id) from account acct2
                   where acct1.id = acct2.id);
```

Now how to get the missing customer from history table?

Thanks.

Comment: what if there are multiple `loan id`s in `loan_history` for a given `cust_id`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, wouldn't that be a simple `NOT IN` clause? See the last line:

```
select loan.id, acct1.number, acct1.type
from loan, acct1
where loan.cust_id = acct1.cust_id
and acct1.id = (select max(acct2.id) from account acct2
                   where acct1.id = acct2.id)
and acct1.id not in (select h.id from loan_history h)     --> this line
```